# Collection sort of list contains 2 objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list, which contains 2 objects of type `Department`s and `Manager`s.

I need to sort the list alphabetically by `Department`s. The `Department` class implements `Comparable<Department>` and has the method `compareTo`. But I receive an error message:

> "The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type
>   Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List, new
>   Comparator(){})"

```
public static List<?> getLst(String fileName)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Object> lst = new LinkedList<>();
    BufferedInputStream f;
    try(ObjectInputStream i = new ObjectInputStream(f=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)))){
        while (f.available()>0) {
            lst.add(i.readObject());
        }

        Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<Department>() {
              @Override
              public int compare(Department object1,Department object2) {
                  return object1.getDepName().compareTo(object2.getDepName());
              }
          });
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: the error message did not displayed correctly.It is "The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>, new Comparator<Department>(){})"

Comment: Well, you can't sort a List<Object> with a Comparator<Department>. You could try creating a Comparator<Object> and see if each of the objects are of type Department.

Comment: You have destroyed Type safety.... Don't create a `List<Object>` instead, if you HAVE to have multiple type within a `List`, create a parent class and have the other classes `extend` off of it.  Then create your list like so `List<`name of parent class`>`.  This will also allow you to define a comparable method, within the parent class, that can be utilized by all children

Comment: In your code, how would you have expected the `Manager` objects to be sorted?

Comment: Is that one manager for each department? Or is it any number of managers and any number of departments mixed between each other?

Comment: You may want to provide an example list and desired result of sorting it.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using generics correctly.

[Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) wants:

- a `List<T>` and
- a matching `Comparator<T>`

You are providing a List of Objects; but a Comparator of Departments. That simply can't work.

So, one way of resolving this - first change your list to use the proper generic type:

```
List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();
```

and later ... add the (now necessary) cast so that the incoming "Object" can be added to that list of departments - if it has the correct type!

```
 Object fromStream = i.readObject();
 if (fromStream instanceof Department) {
    departments.add( (Department) fromStream);
 } else {
   // consider what to do with managers objects ...
```

( please note: `lst` is a bad name; it says **nothing**, and that one saved character *only* adds confusion. Use names that express what the thing behind is about; like `departments` to make clear: something that contains, well departments in plural )

Update: the generics give a hint that you have a **design** problem here. If you want to sort **departments**, then your list containing departments should **not** contain anything else.

In other words: the real answer here is to **not** use *one* list that contains different types of objects, but to use **two** lists instead.

Comment: Thank you for you help.But List contains 2 different objects.Manager cannot be cast to Department

Comment: I see ... but actually: that is not a good approach: it doesnt make sense to put departments and managers in the same list, when you then want to sort "only on departments"! See my updated answer though!

Comment: Thanks again for your help.Its just a part of a task.And I don't know how to do it with 1 list for 2 objects

Comment: Then you have to **step** back and clarify what you are doing. The fact that your **input** consists objects of two different classes **does not** force you to put them all into the same list. And when you want to sort that list, you **can not** put them into the same list in the first place! I reworked my answer to cover that aspect!

Answer (score 0):

The design that puts managers an departments in the same list sounds suspect. Are you making a model for a Tree widget? There are better ways for that ...

In any case, you can do one of two things:

- provide Comaparator and cast inside as needed (bad idea)
- or have both Department and Manager implement HasDepartment with getDepartment() method, and build your Comparator for that.